# Show a `<div>` when the correct password has been entered into a form

Tags: javascript, html, css

I’m creating a page with content on it initially set as hidden. At the top of the page there’s a form asking for a password. Once entered, the `<div>` should display as `block`, but I cannot seem to connect the two functions.

```js
document.querySelector("#pwd").onsubmit(function() {
  if (document.querySelector('#pwd').value == "test123") {
    document.getElementById("#content").style.display = "block";
  }
});
```

```css
#content {
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  background-color: red;
  margin-top: 20px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<form>
  Enter the password to see the content:
  <input id="pwd" type="password" name="pwd" />
</form>
<div id="content">
  Testing Content
</div>
```

Comment: I think all you need to do is change `document.querySelector("#pwd").onsubmit` to `document.querySelector("#pwd").onchange`

Comment: I tried it and no change unfortunately

Comment: `#content` isn’t an ID. The ID is `content`. A text field doesn’t ever dispatch a `submit` event; forms do. The correct way to do this is to change that `<div>` to `<div id="content" hidden>`, remove the `display: none;`, then use this code: `document.querySelector("form").addEventListener("submit", (event) => { event.preventDefault(); if(document.getElementById("pwd").value === "test123"){ document.getElementById("content").hidden = false; } });`.

Comment: Changed the `<div>` as per your instruction. Used the code but still not luck.

Comment: Is your `<script>` _above_ your HTML with no `defer` attribute and no `DOMContentLoaded` or `load` listener and is not `type="module"`? See [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as `getElementById` not find the element?](/q/14028959/4642212). Use the [browser console (dev tools)](//webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`), read any errors.

Answer (score -2):

Try This

```
<html>
<body>
<form id="iniForm" onSubmit="tampil()" action="#">
    Enter the password to see the content:
    <input id="pwd" type="password" name="pwd" />
</form>
<div id="content" style="display:none">
    Testing Content
</div>   
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
<script>
function tampil() {
if(document.getElementById('pwd').value == "test123"){
  document.getElementById('content').style.display='block'
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: [“Try this” answers are not useful](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/298811/4642212). Please add some explanation. Code-only answers are less useful for future readers and don’t explain the OP’s mistake or how to approach the problem.

Comment: Inline event handlers like `onsubmit` are [bad practice](/q/11737873/4642212). They’re an [obsolete, cumbersome, and unintuitive](/a/43459991/4642212) way to listen for events. Always [use `addEventListener`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#inline_event_handlers_%E2%80%94_dont_use_these) instead. Please _never_ suggest or encourage these attributes. The last browser that still needs them reached end of life nearly two decades ago.

Comment: iam sorry, I'm a beginner